# Stop event propagation by clicking inside input element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I am encountering a weird problem here, I have a `div` having an click event attached to it, and a `input` having `on-blur` event  and `button` having click event attached to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div onClick='div()'>
<input onBlur='input()' />
<button onClick='button(event)'> ABCD </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the functions that gets called  when buttons are clicked.

```
function input(event){
    console.log('input')
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function button(event) {
  console.log('button')
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function div(){
  console.log('div')
}
```

The problem that I am encountering here is that, if I click inside the input box then it is logging what is inside the `div` function, I tried `event.stopPropagation()`, but it doesn't seem to work is there any way to make it work? i.e - not logging what is inside div on clicking the input.

Here is a [Bin](https://jsbin.com/kojugabeku/1/edit?html,js,console,output) for the same.

Comment: Note: you're only passing in `event` into one of those functions that needs it.

Comment: @Andy I updated it but it was not causing anyissue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set stop propagation for input click not on blur , 
so the div click will not be propagated :

see below snippet

```js
function input(){
 console.log('input')
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function inputStopPropagation() {
   event.stopPropagation();
}

function button(event) {
  console.log('button')
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function div(){
event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('div')
}
```

```html
<div onClick='div()' style="padding:5px; background :green">
<input onBlur='input()' onClick='inputStopPropagation()' />
<button onClick='button(event)'> ABCD </button>
</div>
```